# style_loader_tag not changing stylesheet to preload

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I am trying to change rel='stylesheet' to rel='preload' using `style_loader_tag` but it isn't doing something. Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag',  'preload_css', 10, 2 );

function preload_css( $html, $handle ){

    $targetHanldes = array('flexible_shipping_notices', 'animate-css');

    if( in_array( $handle, $targetHanldes ) ){

        $html = str_replace("rel='stylesheet'", "rel='preload'", $html);  
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it seems to work fine, my guess is that your `$targetHanldes` containes the wrong handles.

Best option would be to see what `$html` and `$handle` contain and that way you could add them to the haystack.

But for now try this instead

```
$targetHanldes = array('flexible-shipping-notices', 'animate');
```

Again this is pure guess work so you better check the `$html` and `$handle` variables

Comment: ah, this worked for animate but not flexible shipping notices. So, you are right, it must be the handles. I was using the id when I view the source but guess that isn't it. How do I determine the handles?

Comment: @user8463989 You could use [Query monior](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin, this is the best tool when developing in wordpress, there is a sectin there for styles and scripts, you can find the handle there, or just `echo $handle` if you dont have the time (only do this if the site is not live =])